# How to download XCode 4.1

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm a registered developer in apple. I have installed OSX Lion and i want to install XCode but i can download only viersion 4.0.2 which is incompatible for Lion. How to do this?

Comment: There is no such version as 4.1 and version 4.2 is under NDA. Ask at devforums.apple.com

Comment: Well, which version is running on Lion? On site is: "You can download Xcode 4.1 GM Seed from the Mac Dev Center" but Mac Dev Center has only 4.0.2

Comment: There is 4.1 but that is under NDA as well. Have a look carefully at the developer site.

Comment: Please have a look at this link: http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.1_for_lion_21263/installxcode_41_lion.dmg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode Download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529782/xcode-download)

Answer (score 1):

Download version 4.1 from App Store

Comment: Does Xcode 4.1 from App Store allows to choose where I want to install it?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the DMGs for Xcode and other development tools on https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ (requires Apple ID to login).

You must login to have a valid session before downloading anything below.

Xcode 4.1: http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.1_for_lion_21263/installxcode_41_lion.dmg

See this related post: [How to download Xcode DMG or XIP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-7-and-get-the-dmg-file)

Comment: I don't blame you for posting such an answer, because the question really invited you to, but I figured I would tell you that link answers are generally frowned upon when answering questions. Aside from that, Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @Zizouz212 Well, my rationale was like this:

1 - Searched Google and found this post without an answer to the problem
2 - Keep searching (a lot) until I found the solution
3 - Come here and write my post with the solution

Probably (I don't know why) this post has better Google positioning so it appeared before the good one.

To the problem of linking answers, wouldn't be better not to have duplicate answered/unanswered questions?
Not sure if we have a feature to mark them duplicate.