# How do I force install XCode 4.1 from the app store?

Tags: xcode4, app-store

the app store botched its installation of Xcode 4.1 (it turned claimed it was 4.0 but the app store claimed 4.1 was installed). So I deleted the /Developer folder thinking this would let me reinstall a clean Xcode 4.1.

The app store still thinks Xcode 4.1 is installed and will not download or reinstall any version of Xcode. How do I force install Xcode 4.1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download XCode 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663130/how-to-download-xcode-4-1)

Answer (score 15):

Just to explain further...

The App Store download had actually worked

What you saw when you looked at Xcode was your old install, because you had not yet run the installer at that point.

Just find the "XCode installer" in your applications folder and run that to complete the install.

It caught me out too.

Comment: This did the trick for me. Run `/Applications/Install Xcode/Install Xcode.app`. There's also `/Applications/Install Xcode.app`, but that did not work for me, growling at me saying I need the appropriate program for Lion.

Comment: Note that this answer also worked for updating from 4.1 to 4.2 via the app store - it just downloaded an installer, which I had to find and run.

Comment: Note that now the App Store is used for installing Xcode, this no longer applies

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the application "Install Xcode" in your /Applications folder. That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the Install Xcode app works for me - after that I have the opportunity to download that monster all over again

Answer (score 1):

To make a clean installation of Xcode first completely uninstall the previous Xcode version:

From a Terminal window type:

```
$ sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

That process may take a while!

Then try your installation again.

Comment: After running that script the App Store claimed it was still installed.

Comment: Same with me.  I do not know how to refresh the App Store.  I even removed it from Purchases.

Comment: Delete /Applications/Install Xcode.app, and then the App Store recognizes Xcode is gone.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760114/xcode-4-2-on-lion-app-store-thinks-the-app-is-already-installed

Comment: I don't have an "Install Xcode.app" on my machine but I have the same problem as the others. Laaaaaame