# Xcode 4.2 on Lion-- App store thinks the app is already installed

Tags: ios, xcode4

Is any one seeing the issue I m facing. I am trying to upgrade to Xcode 4.2 on my Lion and the app store says it is Installed.

I had a developer preview of 4.2 may be that's the issue.
I went into the launchpad to see if the Install Xcode was there. Yes, it was present there but  it was for 4.1.

Any one know the way to install the Xcode 4.2 on Lion?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution I had to Delete the "Install Xcode" app from ur launch pad for your Xcode to upgrade to 4.2.

Answer (score 6):

Yep, I had the same problem. Here's what fixed it for me:

1. Go to the `Applications` folder and delete `Install Xcode.app`.
2. Go to `.Trash` in your home directory, and manually delete `Install Xcode.app`. I did this in `Terminal.app` by typing the following:

   `sudo rm -rf Install\ Xcode.app`

You could of course combines steps 1 and 2 by executing the `sudo rm` command right in the `Applications` folder, but I felt a little safer doing it this way.

Comment: hey jlehr, thanks for the update.. I found the solution I had to Delete the "Install Xcode" app from ur launch pad for your Xcode to upgrade to 4.2.

Comment: Glad it was that simple for you. I had a tougher time getting it to work yesterday for some reason, and had to go all brute force on it. :-)

Comment: I noticed it even kept the reference to the installer after I'd moved it to a software archive drive (separate volume and everything). It actually updated *that* installer (which I didn't intend) but I didn't notice until a lot of poking around. The lesson, I guess, is if you have the 4.0/4.1 installer around in one or more places, it will likely update one of the copies.