# XCode 4.2 not getting installed on my mac

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2

I want to install XCode 4.2 on my mac. I have the dmg, but when I start the installation process, I get the file size as zero kb. Attaching the screen shot of the same:

[image: Installation window SCode 4.2]

Can anyone tell me what the problem might be???
The Mac version i am using is 10.7.2....
I have tried changing the install location, but it was of no use.
The installation process takes around 15 mins (although the size is zero kbas is in screen shot) and at the end, I am getting the message "Installation Completed"

[image: Installation Process]

[image: installation Successful]

EDIT:
For mac OSX version 10.7.2 (Mac OSx Lion), Do I need to download XCode 4.3. The dmg that I have got from one of my friend is titled "xcode_4.2_and_ios_5_sdk_beta_6_for_snow_leopard.dmg". Also, I have tried installing XCode 3.2.6 and it also is experiencing a similar problem.

Comment: dmg? Have you tried getting it from the app store instead? Also this question is tagged snow leopard and you say you have 10.7, which is it?

Comment: Please check whether the xcode is already installed on your system or not if not then follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760114/xcode-4-2-on-lion-app-store-thinks-the-app-is-already-installed link. Because zero KB for the components is shown when they are already there in the system.

Comment: @jrturton I have edited the question. As far as the use of dmg is concerned, I have got it from one of my friends.

Comment: @Ravin but I have just unpacked my brand new mac (version 10.7.2) and the first thing i did is installing xcode 4.2. So the problem is not regarding upgrading the xcode. Also I can not see the xcode.app in my applications group. But under the developer path in my macintosh hd, i can see a folder named platform containing 2 folders: iPhoneSimulator.platform and iPhoneOS.platform.....

Comment: @anshul I'm not shure if I understand you right. Did you tried to install XCode 4.3 via the App Store? Or do you really need Xcode 4.2?

Comment: generally xcode app is not listed in application group. You will need to search it in your Macintosh HD and see if there is an application with name xcode then unistall it.(do remeber to check its location) if you are having any xcode application code than you can see what are the available options to open the application.(is xcode listed there)

Comment: @Ravin i have searched for XCode in spotlight but I can not see any XCode.app. the only folders I can see (related to XCode) are iPhoneOS.platform and iPhoneSimulator.platform :(

Comment: @TimKrueger No, I have not tried installing XCode 4.3. Since I have the dmg for XCode 4.2 only, so I tried installing that. I just want to know where the problem is?? Do I need to download latest XCode version for Mac OSX 10.7.2 Lion? Can not I Install XCode 4.2 or XCode 3.2.6 on this mac?? Is my dmg not meant for Mac Os 10.7?? I just want to know the real reason behind this

Comment: @anshul XCode4.2 for snow leopard should work on lion also, because its the Mac OX X Lion SDK that it does not cotain but still it has development kit for iOS5 and for snow leopard 10.6.8 or lower versions. Also during installation if you read About Xcode than you will find that it says it requires Mac OS X 10.6.8 or later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded the new dmg of XCode 4.2 from apple developer portal (developement tools). Its XCode_4.2_for_Lion. And it has got installed without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

what have you used for downloading?
The most of download managers downloads damaged files when Internet connection error was occured. The second type of managers stops downloading herein.
Don't use itunes if you can. I advice you to download xcode via torrents because they are protected from these downloading errors. Or at least try to download it via firefox because it stops the downloading instead of masking download erros.

Comment: but the xcode is installed successfully on other mac having version 10.6.8 (using the same dmg that i am trying to use). So the problem is not this.

Answer (score 0):

I read the following in the [Xcode Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051) (developer account required) in the Apple developer documentation:

> ### Installation
>
> - You can install Xcode 4.2 for Mac OS X v10.6 Snow Leopard only if you have purchased an earlier release of Xcode.
> - Install or update Xcode through the Purchases or Updates panes.
> - If you purchased Xcode from the Mac App Store, the Install Xcode app is on the volume on which you installed Xcode.
> - To install Xcode 4.2 on another volume, you must delete all copies of the Install Xcode app from your file system.

Maybe the first point explains your problem!?