# firemonkey for xcode 4.6 or a link to download Xcode 4.1

Tags: xcode, firemonkey, xcode4.6, xcode4.1

I'm using Delphi XE2- firemonkey for iOS app development. the firemonkey-ios.dmg file which is provided in the delphi directory can not be installed with Xcode 4.6. it requires Xcode 4.1 which is no longer available in apple development downloads. (trust me, i looked for it for like a million times!!!)

anybody can help me find a proper firemonkey for Xcode 4.6 or at least a link to download Xcode 4.1 please? i'm using MacOS lion.

Cheers !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download XCode 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663130/how-to-download-xcode-4-1)