# Xcode Download?

Tags: xcode, macos, download, xcode10, xcode9.4

I just upgraded to OS X Mavericks, and I am very excited to be able to use all the new Mavericks technologies. I have just one problem: Where can I download Xcode?

It is not listed in either the updates page in the Mac App Store, or at Apple’s developer website. **Please** tell me that I do not have to be a paid developer-program subscriber to download this update! The real problem is not with Xcode itself, but rather with the 10.9 SDK. Without the header files in the SDK, I cannot tell what the APIs are. As I do not know what the APIs are, I cannot use any developer tool (even those not based on Objective-C).

I also noticed that Apple has not yet updated the Mac Dev Center with info for Mavericks, despite its public release. It is entirely probable that Apple is simply lagging behind with updating the developer website following today’s announcement.

Comment: Patience, it will probably show up in the App Store in the next day or two so if it doesn't by the end of today. Apple usually lags behind a little bit with the developer tools release as they are more focused on getting the new OS out to users. The developer portal hasn't been updated yet to show that 10.9 is out of beta.

Comment: Please be warned, 5.0.1 has been crashing on every startup.
Make sure you have a backup!

Comment: @user2911536: I’m not seeing any instability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it hadn't yet appeared under the (Mac) App Store Updates tab, I was able to search for it and update it that way.

Comment: It appeared in my Updates tab as soon as I saw this.